# How can I restrict a Google Display Network campaign to certain sites?

Tags: google-ads, marketing, ppc

I ran a Google Display Network for a couple of week, providing a number of keywords which (to my knowledge) restrict the sites on which (or the users to whom?) the ads are shown, which as is described in the [Targeting settings on the Display Network](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1209882?hl=en#advanced_targeting)
.

This resulted in a large number of bogus clicks (click fraud) but also in a few sensible conversions. A look at the placements revealed a couple of plausible web pages on which Google decided to show my ad.

I then created a *new* Google Ads campaign for the display network and configured just a few of those placements (but not keywords), assuming that this whitelists those placements but blacklists everything else. However, this campaign gets zero impressions, so I might have misunderstood how targeting by placements works.

Does anybody know how to configure a display network campaign in Google Ads such that the ads are *only* shown on those sites (identified by the host name)?

Comment: hilfreich: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/How-do-I-advertise-in-an-specific-website/td-p/59602